# "abbreviation" for dd$ if current line is empty

Tags: vim

Example:

I type "abc" then `[newline]`. Now I want to effectively just remove the `[newline]` to remove the current line (`dd`) and then jump to the end of "abc" (`$`).

It might seem odd to ask for something shorter than dd$ but doing dd$ instead of using `[backspace]` as it would work in most editors feels out of flow and makes me curious whether there is something more concise.

But maybe `dd$` is already the recommended command for that situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [set <kbd>backspace</kbd> to work like in other editors](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/e6f56a69cfa33d82c21b8fc2d97a6b804e6c835e/.vimrc#L46-L47):

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Sanity's great.

Answer (score 2):

Note: `dd$` only work at the end of the buffer, where the `dd` will automatically move the cursor on line up. Elsewhere, it's `ddk$`.

If you're in insert mode, you can alternatively also use `<BS>` to remove the empty line and move the cursor to the end of the previous line. This also works from normal mode: `i<BS><Esc>` with this setting:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

but it's not shorter.

Why do you need the cursor to be at the end of the previous line (in normal mode)? I don't see that requirement often. If you want to restart editing there, you can just use `A` from anywhere in the line.

Comment: actually the initial state would be insert mode. the situation where you think about starting a new paragraph (newline) and then decide to instead just append another sentence - then you want to just go back to the ende of the last sentence and the newly created line becomes superfluous.

Comment: I don't know what configurations you guys are using, but using the actual vim (vi improved), in insert mode the backspace key performs exactly as in "other editors". Or am I missing something?